# NoScript Web Application

Tags: javascript, php, security

I am building a noscript web application with JavaScript disabled - just HTML, CSS and server-side (PHP). I created the code below to alert users to disable JavaScript to use the web app.

```
<?php
echo '<script type="text/javascript">document.cookie = "noScriptAlert=yes";</script>';

if ($_COOKIE['noScriptAlert'] === 'yes') {
    echo '<small style="position: fixed; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 1;">Please disable Javascript. This web application is designed to work with JavaScript disabled for added security. Once JavaScript is disabled, you need to reload your browser twice (2x) to remove this notice.</small>';
    setcookie('noScriptAlert', '');
}
?>
<noscript>
// NoScript Web Application here...
</noscript>
```

The problem I have is that the user needs to reload the page twice to remove the alert. Is it possible to do this in just one reload? Thank you.

Comment: Why bother with prompting users to disable JS? Why put the content in `<noscript>`? Just write your app without using any JS

Comment: Your issue is that the PHP cookie check occurs on the server-side **before** the client-side JS

Comment: Thanks @Phil. So with the cookie for data access for both client and server side, the straightforward way is just to alert the user to reload twice, right? Aside from cookies, are there any other storage where client and server-side can both access? I did the noscript web app approach as a blanket security measure to prevent JS exploits, so had to write the code inside the <noscript> tag.

Comment: I don't understand what _exploits_ you're trying to prevent.

Comment: XSS and other JS-related vulnerabilities - a more general/blanket approach than escaping, etc. I would not recommend this approach in forward-facing apps though since the user experience will be severely affected. But maybe applicable in internal company apps where JS can be disabled.

Comment: Forget using cookies. Just use JS to show the alert. If it shows, then they have JS enabled

Comment: That is actually a clever idea and the simplest one @Phil. Will use that. Thanks!